# How can i use Orion as the web editor in Xtext?

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I tried to search how i can change the web editor for my Xtext project. But it seems there is missing some documentation.

My question is how can I change the default web editor ace to my prefered editor orion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do two things

1. adapt the workflow to use orion `webSupport = { framework = "Orion"}` (best done before first generation since generate once files will not be overriden)
2. since there is no webjar for orion you need to download/unpack it manually and or separately depending on your build system.

you may have a look at the Yeoman generator-xtext (https://github.com/itemis/generator-xtext) which allows you to create a gradle + xtext + web + orion project.

```
Workflow {

    component = XtextGenerator {
        ...
        language = StandardLanguage {
            name = "org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl"
            fileExtensions = "mydsl"

            serializer = {
                generateStub = false
            }
            validator = {
                // composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
            }
            webSupport = {
                framework = "Orion"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "webSupport = { framework = "Orion"}" is not recognized from the Workflow. Espacially it says that:

Comment: "Couldn't resolve reference to JvmIdentifiableElement 'webSupport'"

Comment: Were did you put it next to validator etc

Comment: My mistake. I thought i had to put it next to "web = ..."